# How to use Ubuntu without entering a password

Tags: password

Is it possible to use Ubuntu without having to enter a password every time? I am getting tired of entering my password whenever I want to use Ubuntu on my own computer. When I was using Windows, I never had to worry about passwords just to enter the system. No one else besides myself uses this computer (and I own the system), so why do I need a password to enter the operating system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it in System Settings

- Under "Brightness & Lock". Simply uncheck "Require my password when waking from suspend".

To also automatically log on when booting up:

- Under "User Accounts" set Automatic Login to On (you need to Unlock the screen first, found in the upper right corner).

Good luck!